Evaluation leak in Derivative[]
Bug introduced in 4, persisting through 14.1.

I usually only report bugs, but in this case, two reason prompted me to post this:

Given that derivatives are computed internally by various commands, one might worry that this bug would be hard to trace; thus it seems worth bringing to community's notice.
Given that derivatives are computed internally by various commands, it would be nice to find a way to prevent the leak.

The variable t below seems to be evaluated while computing the derivative of a Function[] under certain conditions. Cursory experimentation led to these hypothetical conditions needed for the misbehavior:

The number of variables is greater than or equal to 4.
The variable t and at least one variable is differentiated.

Examples
ClearAll[f, a, b, c, s, t, x, y, z];
t = 5;
Derivative[1, 2, 0][f] /.
 f -> Function[{t, x, y}, t^2 x^3 y^4] (* Correct *)
Derivative[1, 2, 0, 0][f] /. 
 f -> Function[{t, x, y, z}, t^2 x^3 y^4 z^5] (* Incorrect *)
Derivative[1, 1, 1, 0][f] /. 
 f -> Function[{t, x, y, z}, Sin[t] x^3 y^4 z^5] (* Incorrect *)
(*
Function[{t, x, y}, (2 x) (6 t y^4)]
Function[{t, x, y, z}, (2 x) (30 y^4 z^5)]
Function[{t, x, y, z}, (4 y^3) (3 x^2 z^5 Cos[5])]
*)

If the total differential order is at least 3 and other variables are set, Derivative[] returns the zero function.
ClearAll[f, a, b, c, s, t, x, y, z];
t = s; x = a; y = b; z = c;
Derivative[1, 1, 0, 0][f] /. f -> Function[{t, x, y, z}, t^2 x^3 y^4 z^5]
Derivative[1, 2, 0, 0][f] /. f -> Function[{t, x, y, z}, t^2 x^3 y^4 z^5]
Derivative[1, 1, 1, 0][f] /. f -> Function[{t, x, y, z}, Sin[t] x^3 y^4 z^5]
(*
Function[{t, x, y, z}, 6 a^2 b^4 c^5 s]
Function[{t, x, y, z}, 0]
Function[{t, x, y, z}, 0]
*)

Instead letting folks hunt far and wide for good examples, I will make the question specific by asking,
How to make the following plot work correctly?
myFunc = Function[{t, x, y, z}, Sin[t] x^3 y^4 z^5];
x = y = z = 1; t =.;
Plot[Derivative[1, 1, 0, 0][myFunc][t, x, 2 y, z], {t, 0, 2 Pi}] 

It should plot 48 Cos[t] but it plots 3 Cos[t] :/
I think others would find it nice if the workaround were convenient in a programming setting.
Reported to WRI, [CASE:5173215]
Forgot to mention: Version 14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)

Even encapsulating the derivative with t as a local variable in a Block or Module the returned result is incorrect. Version 14.

Oh my, it's rather old bug. Version 6: https://i.sstatic.net/wjxV9ptY.png Version 5.2: https://i.sstatic.net/vy5slUo7.png Version 4: https://i.sstatic.net/oTqyEZRA.png Version 3 (Correct): https://i.sstatic.net/GP5NqJyQ.png

@xzczd Thanks! I guess it's not as dangerous as I feared or surely it would have been noticed.

I filed a bug report for this. Thanks for narrowing the examples.

A complete solution
Shortly after posting the half-answer, I thought of a complete answer in a well-duh moment. It basically does the same thing as the half-answer, except it does it for the Derivative[] of a Function[]. The rule for the pattern myD may defined outside InheritedBlock[] to make it persist through a kernel session.
runWithFixedDerivative // Attributes = {HoldAll};
runWithFixedDerivative[code_] := 
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Derivative},
   myD : 
     HoldPattern[Derivative[__][Function[vars_List, __]] /; ! 
        TrueQ[$fixedDerivative]] :=
    Block[{$fixedDerivative = True},
     Block[vars, myD]];
   code];

Tests:
ClearAll[f, a, b, c, s, t, x, y, z, Derivative];
t = s; x = a; y = b; z = c;
runWithFixedDerivative[{
  Derivative[1, 1, 0, 0][f] /. 
   f -> Function[{t, x, y, z}, t^2 x^3 y^4 z^5],
  Derivative[1, 2, 0, 0][f] /. 
   f -> Function[{t, x, y, z}, t^2 x^3 y^4 z^5],
  Derivative[1, 1, 1, 0][f] /. 
   f -> Function[{t, x, y, z}, Sin[t] x^3 y^4 z^5]}]


(*
{Function[{t, x, y, z}, 6 t x^2 y^4 z^5], 
 Function[{t, x, y, z}, (2 x) (6 t y^4 z^5)], 
 Function[{t, x, y, z}, (4 y^3) (3 x^2 z^5 Cos[t])]}
*)


myFunc = Function[{t, x, y, z}, Sin[t] x^3 y^4 z^5];
x = y = z = 1; Clear[t];
Plot[
 Derivative[1, 1, 0, 0][myFunc][t, x, 2 y, z],
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}] // runWithFixedDerivative




Original half-answer
Here's a half answer. It is an answer in that it produces the correct plot. It is incomplete in that I have to hack the code instead of fixing Derivative and running the code. An excellent answer might be of the following form:
runWithFixedDerivative // Attributes = {HoldAll};
runWithFixedDerivative[code_] := ...

With such a solution, I wouldn't have to worry about editing the code once the bug in Derivative is fixed.
I offer the answer in case it gives someone an idea. Also, it's nice to have an ad hoc fix in case nothing better turns up.
myFunc = Function[{t, x, y, z}, Sin[t] x^3 y^4 z^5];
x = y = z = 1; t = 5; (* works even for t=5 *)
Plot[
 Block[{t, x, y, z}, Derivative[1, 1, 0, 0][myFunc][t, x, 2 y, z]],
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}]


It's a little faster with Evaluated -> True, but with t=5, one cannot use Evaluate[] on the first argument.
Why does it work?
Each time Plot[] evaluates the argument at some value of t, it evaluate Block[..], and Derivative[] is computed inside the Block[] environment with the values of t, x, y, and z unset.  This returns the correct symbolic derivative which is the expression-value of Block[]. This expression is evaluate outside of Block[] with x = y = z = 1 and t re-set by Plot[] equal to whatever value between 0 and 2 Pi it is evaluating. With Evaluated -> True, Plot[] evaluates the argument Block[..] with t already blocked; the evaluation sequence just explained results in the correct derivative evaluated with x = y = z = 1 but with t unset. This expression is then plotted. It is faster because Derivative[] is computed only once and not at each step.
P.S.
Note that Evaluated is a useful option that is not simply equivalent to using Evaluate[], as seen in this example. It is unfortunate that it is not documented.

The permanent solution is to wait until 14.2 comes out, in which I have fixed the bug.  Perhaps not immediately useful for folks, but quite robust. :)
For the curious, there were a couple of places where the product rule was applied a bit carelessly, allowing global values to seep in.  Of course, the cost is that if you hit those places, you may now see an unevaluated sum.  So, for example, whereas these previously gave the same answer, they now differ because one is using the product rule and the other the power rule:
Function[x,x^2]'                                                      
(* Function[x, 2 x] *)

Function[x,x*x]'                                                      
(* Function[x, x 1 + x 1] *)

Obviously, once you apply the derivative to some values, everything the evaluate the same final result.

After some deep digging in function construction, the point seems to be, that the right side of a function, its body, is evaluated during replacement processes. That's functional, because Replace does not respect any Hold attributes and so can be used to change without any restrictions the function body of an already defined, protected function.
As a user interested in functional algebra, one has to know what one is doing, when passing the border between algebra and unrestricted symbol manipulation, typical for programmable editors and String manipulation functions in Mathematica using Regular Expressions.

Is this an answer? I am not sure what is your point, can you clarify? Are you justifying that output?

I think the replacement is a red-herring. I thought it made it easier to understand the differences in the functions and derivative. Derivative fails with no use of Replace or ReplaceAll: t = s; x = a; y = b; z = c; Derivative[1, 1, 1, 0][Function[{t, x, y, z}, Sin[t] x^3 y^4 z^5]]. Note that in the specific question users are asked to answer, there is also no replacement. There is no use of strings or regular expressions, so I have no idea why you bring that up.
